# How to combine same entry in multiple lists in json response

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I have a quite complex json response which I have to combine, but im totally stuck. I didnt find a smart and effective way yet to detect all `votedpositive` matches of all users.

```
  participants =  {
      "data": [
        {
          "userId": 2,
          "votedPositive": [
            {
              "userId": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "userId": 3,
          "votedPositive": [
            {
              "userId": 5
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "userId": 4,
          "votedPositive": []
        },
        {
          "userId": 5,
          "votedPositive": [
            {
              "userId": 2,
            },
            {
              "userId": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "userId": 6,
          "votedPositive": []
        },
        {
          "userId": 7,
          "votedPositive": []
        },
        {
          "userId": 8,
          "votedPositive": []
        },
        {
          "userId": 9,
          "votedPositive": []
        },
        {
          "userId": 10,
          "votedPositive": []
        },
        {
          "userId": 11,
          "votedPositive": []
        },
        {
          "userId": 12,
          "votedPositive": []
        },
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "votedPositive": [
            {
              "userId": 2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

The output im expecting is a list or array with all the matching pairs. in the above example I would expect to get the information that `userId 2` who voted `userId 1` has a match because `UserId 1` voted `userId 2`. Same goes for `userId 3` and `userId 5`.

EDIT: This is what I have so far:

```
var participantsList = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < participants.length; index++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < participants[index]["votedPositive"].length; i++) {
      participantsList.push([participants[index]["userId"], participants[index]["votedPositive"][i]["userId"]])
    }
  }
  
for (var index = 0; index < participantsList.length; index++) {
    participantsList[index].sort(function (a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });
  }
```

I created a list where im iterating based on the length of all the user ids and im pushing the userid and the voted id. After that I sorted the list so I can see duplicates now. Im not sure if it is working until here. The next step would be to filter out all duplicate combinations in another list, thats where im stuck right now.

The result I have right now is this:

```
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 1, 2 ] ]
```

Comment: Object properties have to have unique names. You can't have duplicate properties named `match`.

Comment: i only need to know the 2 ids matching, it doesnt have to be the exact same ouput

Comment: `{ "userId": 2, "userId": 3}` is also not possible.

Comment: I can't figure out how that output is related to the input. What are you using for the grouping?

Comment: I edited my question. I only need to know the pairs regarding to all users and their positive votes who are matching with the counterpart. sorry for the bad description, I hope its more clear now

Comment: Try iterating through the array and building a directed graph of the votes, then you can check the edges in that graph to find matching pairs between two nodes. 

But also, what approaches have you tried so far? Any specific places you’re getting stuck on?

Comment: thank your for your response. I updated my question so you can see my current progress and where im stuck at. Im not sure yet if this approach will be working in all cases

Comment: You still haven't fixed the invalid input data. Is `"votedPositive": [{"userId": 2, "userId": 3}]` supposed to be `"votedPositive": [{"userId": 2}, {"userId": 3}]`?

Comment: @Barmar yes your'e right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object whose keys are the voters and values are a set of the users they voted for. Then you can go through this and find the pairs that voted for each other.

```js
participants = {
  "data": [{
      "userId": 2,
      "votedPositive": [{
        "userId": 1
      }]
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "votedPositive": [{
        "userId": 5
      }]
    },
    {
      "userId": 4,
      "votedPositive": []
    },
    {
      "userId": 5,
      "votedPositive": [{
          "userId": 2,
        },
        {
          "userId": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "userId": 6,
      "votedPositive": []
    },
    {
      "userId": 7,
      "votedPositive": []
    },
    {
      "userId": 8,
      "votedPositive": []
    },
    {
      "userId": 9,
      "votedPositive": []
    },
    {
      "userId": 10,
      "votedPositive": []
    },
    {
      "userId": 11,
      "votedPositive": []
    },
    {
      "userId": 12,
      "votedPositive": []
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "votedPositive": [{
        "userId": 2
      }]
    }
  ]
}

const votedFor = new Map();

participants.data.forEach(({
  userId,
  votedPositive
}) => {
  if (!votedPositive.length) {
    return;
  }
  if (!votedFor[userId]) {
    votedFor.set(userId, new Set());
  }
  votedPositive.forEach(({
      userId: target
    }) =>
    votedFor.get(userId).add(target)
  );
});

const result = [];

votedFor.forEach((votees, voter) =>
  votees.forEach(votee => {
    if (votedFor.get(votee) && votedFor.get(votee).has(voter)) {
      result.push([voter, votee]);
    }
  })
);

console.log(result);
```